# return out of function

Tags: python, return

Hi im working on a code but it is not working because i get the error: 'return' out of function

here is my code

```
def get_information():
    names_list=[]
    coursework_marks_list=[]
    prelim_marks_list=[]

    file=open("details.txt","r")
for line in file:
    item=line.split()
    if len(item)>1:
        names_list.append(item[0])
        coursework_marks_list.append(item[1])
        prelim_marks_list.append(item[2])

    return names_list,coursework_marks_list,prelim_marks_list
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Indentation](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) is *everything* in Python. Your `return` statement is out of the [scope](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) of your function. You need to remedy it like so:

```
def get_information():
    names_list=[]
    coursework_marks_list=[]
    prelim_marks_list=[]

    file=open("details.txt","r")
    for line in file:
        item=line.split()
        if len(item)>1:
            names_list.append(item[0])
            coursework_marks_list.append(item[1])
            prelim_marks_list.append(item[2])

    return names_list,coursework_marks_list,prelim_marks_list
```

You should also read & follow [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).